# Build documentation that is behind symlinks

Tags: symbolic-link

I've built an internal documentation site using [Material for MkDocs](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material) but I would like to provide multiple project readmes by symlinking folders from their own git repos into the `docs/` folder. That is, given two projects:

1. `/home/user/projects/first_project.git` which has documentation in `Guide/`
2. `/projects/second_project.git` which has its documentation also in `Guide/`

I can copy `/home/user/projects/first_project/Guide` into the `docs/` directory and it serves the necessary documentation.

But since I don't want to potentially forget to `rsync` folders, I thought I should symlink them:

```
ln -s /home/user/projects/first_project/Guide docs/first_project_guide
ln -s /projects/second_project/Guide docs/second_project_guide
```

This lets me access the separate guide folders in the command line, but mkdocs doesn't seem to know how to build through symlinks. Does anyone know how I can configure mkdocs to do so?

This is the error I see:

```bash
INFO    -  [01:57:11] Detected file changes
INFO    -  Building documentation...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mkdocs/livereload/__init__.py", line 193, in _build_loop
    func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mkdocs/commands/serve.py", line 67, in builder
    build(config, live_server=None if is_clean else server, dirty=is_dirty)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mkdocs/commands/build.py", line 337, in build
    files.copy_static_files(dirty=dirty, inclusion=inclusion)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mkdocs/structure/files.py", line 111, in copy_static_files
    file.copy_file(dirty)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mkdocs/structure/files.py", line 290, in copy_file
    utils.copy_file(self.abs_src_path, self.abs_dest_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mkdocs/utils/__init__.py", line 132, in copy_file
    shutil.copyfile(source_path, output_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 256, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/docs/first_project_guide'
```

Comment: I'd tag this with [mkdocs] and [material-mkdocs] but I don't have enough reputation here to create tags...

Comment: Did you include the symlink in MkDocs' `nav`? It looks like it's trying to open it as a file, which should not happen. Make sure directories or symlinks to directories are not included in the navigation (unless using a plugin like mkdocs-literate-nav).

Comment: @pawamoy nope, I'm not including it in the nav, I made symlinks to the respective projects in the mkdocs source directory.

Comment: OK, well, it's hard to guess without a reproducible example. Feel free to open a new issue with such an example on MkDocs' bugtracker (https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs).

Comment: Hmm... thanks. I'm not sure this isn't reproducible, though, but I'll try to craft something. Cheers!